# Question about p.192 in Schwartz, Quantum field theory (Regarding the rewriting of the Majorana mass)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory, majorana-fermions

I'am reading the Schwartz's Quantum field theory and Standard model p.192 and some question arises:

[image]

Why the underlined equality is true? Here, $\bar{\psi} : = \psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$ is the conjugate field (his book p.171, (10.88) )(true?)

My first attempt to calculate that is as follows :

Case 1) If $\gamma^{0}$ means $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{2} \\ \sigma^{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
($\sigma_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the Pauli matrices), as his book p.170, then

$$\frac{m}{2}\bar{\psi}\psi = \frac{m}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L \\ i\sigma_2\psi_L^{*} \end{pmatrix}^{\dagger} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{2} \\ \sigma^{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L  \\ i\sigma_2 \psi_L^{*} \end{pmatrix} 
 = \frac{m}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \psi_L^{\dagger} & -i\sigma_2^{\dagger}\psi_L^{T} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{2} \\ \sigma^{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L  \\ i\sigma_2 \psi_L^{*} \end{pmatrix} 
 =  i\frac{m}{2} (\psi_L^{\dagger}\sigma^{2}\sigma_{2}\psi_L^{*}-\psi_L^{T}\sigma_2^{\dagger}\sigma^{2}\psi_L )$$

Case 2) If $\gamma^{0}$ means $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ then I could deduce the underlined equality.

This is a point that I've reached. Perhaps, I made a mistake? Then which part am I confused about?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: See also: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: Seems to be using chiral basis i.,e., $\gamma_0=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ That's maybe why you can get the expression using it in that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $\gamma_0$ in the *[Chiral basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis)*.

In this basis, the gamma matrices take the form $$\gamma^0=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad , \quad \gamma^j=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sigma^j \\ -\sigma^j & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

So,

$$\frac{m}{2}\bar{\psi}\psi= \frac{m}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \psi_L \\ i\sigma_2\psi_L^{*} \end{bmatrix}^{\dagger} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \psi_L  \\ i\sigma_2 \psi_L^{*} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ = \frac{m}{2}\begin{bmatrix} \psi_L^{\dagger} & -i\sigma_2^{\dagger}\psi_L^{T} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \psi_L  \\ i\sigma_2 \psi_L^{*} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\frac{m}{2} [-i\sigma_2^\dagger \psi_L^T\ 
 \quad \psi_L^\dagger]\begin{bmatrix} \psi_L  \\ i\sigma_2 \psi_L^{*} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\frac{m}{2} (-i\psi_L\sigma_2^\dagger  \psi_L^T
 +i\psi_L^\dagger\sigma_2\psi_L^*]$$

$$=i\frac{m}{2} [\psi_L^{\dagger}\sigma_2\psi_L^*-\psi_L^{T}\sigma_2\psi_L ]$$